# How to select a property inside a span, using XPath selectors?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to select the address of a company using XPath selectors, so that I can later insert it in my Spider in Scrapy. So, my goal is to extract the address, in this case only **'Address 123'**. I now have to following XPath selector:

```
> response.xpath('//span[@property="streetAddress"]').get()
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
'<span class="partners__info-value" property="streetAddress">Address 123</span>'
```

Can anybody help me to select **only** 'Address 213'??
The html code is can be seen in the picture below.

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OONL2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text **Address 123** you need to use `text()` as follows:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="partners__info-value" and @property="streetAddress"]/text()')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `text()` to extract the text of an element:

```
response.xpath('//span[@property="streetAddress"]/text()')
```

[Example xpather](http://xpather.com/ZkJhZsvS)